# Django : use uuslug with allow unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode

I'm using `django.utils.text.slugify` to generate slug and this function has `allow_unicode` parameter; when I want to generate slug by Unicode characters like Persian and Arabic, I used this.

Now I want work with `uuslug` and need to generate slug with Unicode characters.

What's your suggestion to do that?

Comment: `uuslug` handles Unicode. What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I use `django.utils.text.slugify`:
`slugify('آموزش کار با جانگو', allow_unicode=True)`

and output is:
`آموزش-کار-با-جانگو`

But `uuslug` output is:
`amwzsh-khr-b-jngw`